# How use JQuery each function in typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I want to get class/attr of each checkbox. Code sample is given below.

```
  jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").each(()=> {
      let checkboxID = jQuery(this).attr("class");
      console.log(checkboxID);//output undefined
      console.log(this.atc1List); //typescript variable 
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

Inside arrow function `this` refers to your class instance so update your code as follows, where the second argument in callback refers to the element.

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").each((i, ele) => {
  let checkboxID = jQuery(ele).attr("class");
  console.log(checkboxID);//output undefined
  console.log(this.atc1List); //typescript variable 
});
```

As per [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own **this**, arguments, super, or new.target.

Comment: @PalashKantiBachar : glad to help you